# Getting elements from another xml in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

In my MainActivity.class I have

```
ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnElementInside_items_xml);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I can't access this button in my MainActivity, just elements in activity_main.xml. How can I access elements from others .xml files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to access `Button` with `ImageView` object

Do this instead

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.btnElementInside_items_xml);
```

Or you can change the element in your xml to `ImageView` instead of a `Button`